# After running the server in django, I am getting the KeyError: 'django'

Tags: django, error-handling

I am not fluent in Django,been doing for over 3 months now, BUT I have never seen such error. Please if someone can help me out of this situation.

I am doing the short_url module, bt befoe that i have pip installed shorturls , then i created an app shorturls. Again , i have to delte the app shorturls. And after that i have been facing this issue.

Following is my full traceback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\shorturls\templatetags\shorturl.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.core import urlresolvers
ImportError: cannot import name 'urlresolvers' from 'django.core' (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\__init__.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\blink\myblink\manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\blink\myblink\manage.py", line 19, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 61, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 96, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 103, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 637, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 622, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 327, in run
    autoreload_started.send(sender=self)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 180, in send
    return [
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 181, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\autoreload.py", line 41, in watch_for_template_changes
    for directory in get_template_directories():
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\autoreload.py", line 14, in get_template_directories
    for backend in engines.all():
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 25, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 123, in get_package_libraries
    raise InvalidTemplateLibrary(
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'shorturls.templatetags.shorturl': cannot
import name 'urlresolvers' from 'django.core' (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\__init__.py)
```

Comment: I assume you are using this package [django-shorturls](https://github.com/bfirsh/django-shorturls)? It seems that it is not maintained and will not work from Django version 2.0 onwards (`django.core.urlresolvers` was removed in 2.0)

Comment: i am using django-shorturls. if its not maintained , its ok. Now, how will i remove this error. I cant run my server @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: You will simply _remove_ the package (not use it) since it will not work for Django versions 2.0 onwards. Or you will downgrade to a lower version of Django.

Comment: ok. It will be very thankful, can u suggest me how can i generate shorturls for my urls and display it on templates.